# Xpath: how to select an option based on its text not value property?

Tags: xpath

consider both types:

```
<select name="garden">
    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
```

Is `@val` for actually indicating the `value=""` attribute ?

Is `@value` for indicating the innerText value ?

for example what happens if `<option>` doesn't contain any `value=""` property. how would you select it then ?

```
select/option[@value = "Grass"]
```

Does Xpath automatically ignore white spaces for the case above? Should it be trimmed?

EDIT:

for selecting multiple options would this suffice ?

```
select/option[normalize-space(text())="Grass" or normalize-space(text())="Trees"]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To select by text value you can use `text()` function. And normalize spaces is required, because they are not removed by default. Here is an example:

```
select/option[normalize-space(text())="Grass"]
```

`@value` - value of "value" attribute

`@val` - value of "val" attribute

[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-normalize-space) - function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space

Comment: for selecting multiple options would this suffice ?

select/option[normalize-space(text())="Grass" or normalize-space(text())="Trees"]

Comment: It's okay, except that `text()` is not a function. It's a node test. And Marc's answer is both shorter, and more idiomatic for XPath.

Comment: BTW, how `text()` should be called (if it's not a function)?

Answer (score 12):

Well, if whitespace isn't an issue:

```
/select/option[.='Grass']
```

I'd need to check re whitespace, though. You could always normalize:

```
/select/option[normalize-space(.)='Grass']
```

Comment: for selecting multiple options would this suffice ?

select/option[normalize-space(.)="Grass" or normalize-space(.)="Trees"]

Comment: This seems to be case-sensitive. Is there a way to make this otherwise?

Comment: @Timur: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath