# case-insensitive matching in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

For example, for the XML below

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD title="Empire Burlesque"/>
    <CD title="empire burlesque"/>
    <CD title="EMPIRE BURLESQUE"/>
    <CD title="EmPiRe BuRLeSQuE"/>
    <CD title="Others"/>
<CATALOG>
```

How to match the first 4 records with xpath like `//CD[@title='empire burlesque']`. Is there xpath function to do this? Other solutions like PHP function are also accepted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt

check out ben gripka's post for xpath 1.0

Comment: Here, I also have found 2 more solutions with description: (not my site/promotion) https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-xpath-case-sensitivity-with-php

Answer (score 135, accepted):

XPath 2 has a lower-case (and upper-case) string function.  That's not quite the same as case-insensitive, but hopefully it will be close enough:

```
//CD[lower-case(@title)='empire burlesque']
```

If you are using XPath 1, there is a [hack using translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide/1625859#1625859).

Comment: Even works in SQL Server's XPath queries on XML columns. Excellent.

Answer (score 69):

**[matches()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) is an XPATH 2.0 function that allows for case-insensitive regex matching.**

One of the [flags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags) is `i` for case-insensitive matching.

The following XPATH using the [matches()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function with the case-insensitive flag:

```
//CD[matches(@title,'empire burlesque','i')]
```

Comment: This is regex-based which is an important difference to text-based matching.

Comment: Beware that this may also find partial matches; if that's not acceptable then use `^` and `$`, like `matches(@title, '^empire burlesque$', 'i')`

Answer (score 16):

This does not work in Chrome Developer tools to locate a element, i am looking to locate the 'Submit' button in the screen

```
//input[matches(@value,'submit','i')]
```

However, using 'translate' to replace all caps to small works as below

```
//input[translate(@value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'submit']
```

Update: I just found the reason why 'matches' doesnt work. I am using Chrome with xpath 1.0 which wont understand the syntax 'matches'. It should be xpath 2.0

Comment: It seems the translate concept is called 'case insensitive collation' in regards to internationalization

Comment: Also bear in mind that the `translate` solution in this answer won't work for languages (german for instance) having special rules for uppercase letters.

Answer (score 10):

One possible PHP solution:

```php
// load XML to SimpleXML
$x = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

// index it by title once
$index = array();
foreach ($x->CD as &$cd) {
  $title = strtolower((string)$cd['title']); 
  if (!array_key_exists($title, $index)) $index[$title] = array();
  $index[$title][] = &$cd;
}

// query the index 
$result = $index[strtolower("EMPIRE BURLESQUE")];
```

Comment: To the anonymous down-voter: Read the OP's question. Especially the *"Other solutions like PHP function are also accepted."* part.

Answer (score 9):

for selenium xpath lower-case will not work ... Translate will help
Case 1 :

1. using Attribute
   //*[translate(@id,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='login_field']
2. Using any attribute
   //*[translate(@*,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='login_field']

Case 2 : (with contains)
//[contains(translate(@id,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'login_field')]

case 3 : for Text property
//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'username')]

Comment: You helped me a lot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that PHP solutions were acceptable, and PHP does offer a way to accomplish this even though it only supports XPath v1.0. You can extend the XPath support to allow PHP function calls.

```
$xpathObj = new DOMXPath($docObj);
$xpathObj->registerNamespace('php','http://php.net/xpath'); // (required)
$xpathObj->registerPhpFunctions("strtolower"); // (leave empty to allow *any* PHP function)
$xpathObj->query('//CD[php:functionString("strtolower",@title) = "empire burlesque"]');
```

See the [PHP registerPhpFunctions](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) documentation for more examples. It basically demonstrates that "php:function" is for boolean evaluation and "php:functionString" is for string evaluation.