# Find case-insensitive string and replace (PHP)

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm using SimpleXML to get some data from an XML document and if the data contains a search term then I want it highlighted. So the user would first enter a search term and then the XML document is processed, element by element, and a string search performed. I already know how to use SimpleXML but what I'm not very sure is how to find a case-insensitive string and replace it with itself plus some markup.

- User enters "brown fox" (without the quotes) as a search term.
- Web server loops through all XML elements and looks for a case-insensitive match (one or more per element).
- If there is a match (one or more) the case-insensitive term is replaced with itself and some HTML code for markup. Otherwise the element text is just outputed without markup.

If the document contains: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." then the output should be the same string but with "brown fox" highlighted via CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [case-insensitive matching in xpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  As written, we have no context to insert a solution into your current code.

Comment: A solution does not have to fit into my code. I'm using XML but a simple string sample would suffice.

Comment: You are basically asking us to write all parts of the code for you, which isn't how SO works.  Give us a starting a point and tell us where you're stuck, then you'll get constructive answers.

Comment: I've got the XML processing code and a lot more. The question has already been answered, didn't take much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
<?php
$html = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$replace = preg_replace('/\A(.*?)(brown fox)(.*?)\z/sim', '$1<span STYLE="font-size: x-large; color: #ffffff">$2</span>$3', $html);
echo $replace;
// The quick <span STYLE="font-size: x-large; color: #ffffff">brown fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog
?>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/da8hvv)

Comment: It does, I was however hoping that I could do it without regular expressions since they don't make any sense to me. Can you explain what all those symbols mean?

Comment: Can you rewrite the regular expression so that it highlights multiple terms?