# Selecting lines matching keywords using XPATH

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to print all lines starting with a "+" and which have a keyword such as "hasRole".

```
String search="//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') and contains(text(),'hasRole')]";
```

I know a simple and condition will not be enough. How do I formulate the XPATH search for this?

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Also,how do I make this search case insensitive?

Comment: can you add the html fragment as text in the question?

Comment: Check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath

Comment: @Jon tried but does not work in my case. I have to use with contains

Comment: Do not show markup in images. Please replace this screenshot with an sample of your HTML input that people can use to _test_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below and it worked.

```
String search="//td[(contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') and contains(.,'HasRole')) or (contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion') and contains(.,'HasRole'))]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
//td[(contains(lower-case(@class), 'blob-code blob-code-addition') ...
```

OR

```
//td[(contains(translate(@class, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 'blob-code blob-code-addition') ...
```

Comment: I want to match "hasRole" with ignore case. I am not concerned about the class

Comment: It's the same.

... contains(lower-case(.),'hasrole') ...

OR

... contains(translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 'hasrole') ...