# Case insensitive xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How would I match the following two items with one xpath?

```
<locales>
        <locale name="nl-NL">
</locales>

<locales>
        <locale name="NL-NL">
</locales>
```

So far I have a case-sensitive match of:

```
//locales/locale[@name="nl-NL"]
```

Comment: already asked. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following XPATH:

```
//locales/locale[translate(@name,'nl','NL')='NL-NL']
```

Or, if there are just two values, you can use even this:

```
//locales/locale[@name='NL-NL' or @name = 'nl-NL']
```