# Find element name via case-insensitive search

Tags: xpath

Given the following three pieces of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <body>
        <customerSearchRequest>
            <id>1234</id>
        </customerSearchRequest>
    </body>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <BODY>
        <userSearchRequest>
            <id>5678</id>
        </userSearchRequest>
    </BODY>
</root>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Body>
        <orderSearchRequest>
            <id>9101</id>
        </orderSearchRequest>
    </Body>
</root>
```

I need to extract the name of the first-child of `body` (i.e. `customerSearchRequest`, `userSearchRequest` and `orderSearchRequest`), which I am currently doing as follows:

```
name(//SOAP-ENV:body/*[1])
```

The problem is, this only works for the first request as `body` is case-sensitive. How do I make the path case-insensitive?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this :

```
name(//SOAP-ENV:*[translate(local-name(),'BODY','body')='body']/*[1])
```

The following part first finds elements in namespace of `SOAP-ENV`, and then filter to those with local-name equals 'body', case-insensitive :

```
//SOAP-ENV:*[translate(local-name(),'BODY','body')='body']
```

If you have XPath 2.0 available, it can be done in a cleaner way using `lower-case()`, `upper-case()`, or regex based functions like `matches()` : [case-insensitive matching in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath)

Comment: Correct answer, but also note that OP should consider pushing back to party responsible for the XML to standardize on a single case convention since `body`, `BODY`, and `Body` are really three distinct elements.

Comment: I'm using logstash, which uses Nokogiri, which doesn't support XPath 2 so my final solution is `local-name(//*[translate(local-name(),'BODY','body')='body']/*[1])`