# Find href children with specific text

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I wish to extract a link on a set of pages. Sometimes this link is defined on a page as:

```
//*[@id="mainlist"]/dl/dt[3]/a
```

and sometimes as:

```
//*[@id="mainlist"]/dl[2]/dt[2]/a
```

The text associated with the link is always "My special link".

Is there a way to match a href child of `//*[@id="mainlist"]` which has the text "My special link"?

Comment: added testable html fragment would be good

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549256/6241235    ,   https://stackoverflow.com/q/17329436/6241235 .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
"//*[@id="mainlist"]//a[text()="My special link"]"
```

With cssselect you can do

```
"#mainlist a:contains("My special link")"
```