# XSL: Create group based on attribute count and match

Tags: xml, xslt, count, grouping, xslt-1.0

I am trying to insert a container when the count of an attribute = X and a 2nd group based on the value of an attribute. The two attributes are not related.

Using XSLT- V1

I would like to first group based on the value of an attribute. Ie. anytime ID=01 would create a group. I would then like to insert a new attribute/ container when the count = X.

I am able to group based on attribute value, but not sure how to determine count and add a new container.

I have XML that looks like the following:

```
<Items>
  <Details>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <Name>Name for 01</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>01-A</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User2</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>US</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <Name>Name for 01</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>01-B</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User3</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>CN</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <ID>02</ID>
    <Name>Name for 02</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>02-A</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User4</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>MX</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <ID>03</ID>
    <Name>Name for 03</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>03-A</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>CA</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <ID>02</ID>
    <Name>Name for 02</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>02-B</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>AU</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <ID>01</ID>
    <Name>Name for 01</Name>
    <Owner>User1</Owner>
    <Rev>02-C</Rev>
    <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
    <Rev_Code>JP</Rev_Code>
  </Details>
</Items>
```

I have below XSL that creates expected group for item ID

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="ItemGroup" match="Details" use="ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Items>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Details[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroup',ID)[1])]">
    <ItemID name="{ID}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('ItemGroup',ID)"/>
    </ItemID>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Details[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroup',ID)[1]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output for aboe XSL:

```
<Items>
  <ItemID name="01">
      <Details>
         <ID>01</ID>
         <Name>Name for 01</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>01-A</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User2</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>US</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      <Details>
         <ID>01</ID>
         <Name>Name for 01</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>01-B</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User3</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>CN</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      <Details>
         <ID>01</ID>
         <Name>Name for 01</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>02-C</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>JP</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
   </ItemID>

  <ItemID name="02">
      <Details>
         <ID>02</ID>
         <Name>Name for 02</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>02-A</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User4</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>MX</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      <Details>
         <ID>02</ID>
         <Name>Name for 02</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>02-B</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>AU</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
   </ItemID>
  <ItemID name="03">
      <Details>
         <ID>03</ID>
         <Name>Name for 03</Name>
         <Owner>User1</Owner>
         <Rev>03-A</Rev>
         <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
         <Rev_Code>CA</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
   </ItemID>


</Items>
```

I would now like to add a variable for count of "details" = 3 for example (it would really be somewhere between 1,000- 5,000) and then expect below output

```
<Items>
  <Split>
      <ItemID name="01">
      <Details>
        <ID>01</ID>
        <Name>Name for 01</Name>
        <Owner>User1</Owner>
        <Rev>01-A</Rev>
        <Rev_Owner>User2</Rev_Owner>
        <Rev_Code>US</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <ID>01</ID>
        <Name>Name for 01</Name>
        <Owner>User1</Owner>
        <Rev>01-B</Rev>
        <Rev_Owner>User3</Rev_Owner>
        <Rev_Code>CN</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <ID>01</ID>
        <Name>Name for 01</Name>
        <Owner>User1</Owner>
        <Rev>02-C</Rev>
        <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
        <Rev_Code>JP</Rev_Code>
      </Details>
      </ItemID>
  </Split>
  <Split>
  <ItemID name="02">
    <Details>
      <ID>02</ID>
      <Name>Name for 02</Name>
      <Owner>User1</Owner>
      <Rev>02-A</Rev>
      <Rev_Owner>User4</Rev_Owner>
      <Rev_Code>MX</Rev_Code>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <ID>02</ID>
      <Name>Name for 02</Name>
      <Owner>User1</Owner>
      <Rev>02-B</Rev>
      <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
      <Rev_Code>AU</Rev_Code>
    </Details>
  </ItemID>
  <ItemID name="03">
    <Details>
      <ID>03</ID>
      <Name>Name for 03</Name>
      <Owner>User1</Owner>
      <Rev>03-A</Rev>
      <Rev_Owner>User5</Rev_Owner>
      <Rev_Code>CA</Rev_Code>
    </Details>
  </ItemID>
  </Split>
  <Split>
     continued....

</Items>
```

many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath: how to select an option based on its text not value property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549256/xpath-how-to-select-an-option-based-on-its-text-not-value-property)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the XSLT you have got so far. Thank you!

Comment: In a first step, do the `group-by="ID"` in a variable and then in a second step use positional grouping on the result of the first step. If you need further help then please state which XSLT processor and/or which XSLT version you use/can use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at least XSLT 2 you can use two grouping steps, the first is a simple `group-by` on the `ID` child element, the second then does positional grouping the result of the first step:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

   <xsl:param name="split-size" as="xs:integer" select="3"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Items">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:variable name="groups">
               <xsl:for-each-group select="Details" group-by="ID">
                   <ItemID name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                   </ItemID>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="$groups/ItemID/Details" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $split-size">
               <split>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/.."/>
               </split>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9n

With XSLT 1, to perform a two step transformation, you need to use `exsl:node-set` or similar (depending on the particular XSLT processor used) to convert the result tree fragment from the first grouping step back into a node set so that you can select and navigate it; furthermore the positional "grouping" or splitting requires some selection along the siblings axis:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

   <xsl:param name="split-size" select="3"/>

   <xsl:key name="group" match="Details" use="ID"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="Items">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:variable name="groups">
               <xsl:for-each select="Details[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', ID)[1])]">
                   <ItemID name="{ID}">
                       <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', ID)"/>
                   </ItemID>
               </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="Details" select="exsl:node-set($groups)/ItemID/Details"/>
           <xsl:for-each select="$Details[position() mod $split-size = 1]">
               <split>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="(. | (following-sibling::Details | ../following-sibling::ItemID/Details)[position() &lt; $split-size])/.."/>
               </split>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9n/2

Comment: @Tim C i have edited the question with the XSLT i have at the moment

Comment: thank you for your response. I need to use XSLT 1- my apologies for not stating in the initial post.

Comment: this is exactly what i need but using XSLT 1.0. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @Chris, I have added an XSLT 1 sample, will probably not perform well on large inputs due to the following-sibling axis use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your existing key, I think you need another key (which would be used first) to group the Details by whether they have ID = 01 or not

```
<xsl:key name="ItemGroupOne" match="Details" use="ID = '01'"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="ItemGroupOne" match="Details" use="ID = '01'"/>
  <xsl:key name="ItemGroup" match="Details" use="ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Items>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Details[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroupOne',ID = '01')[1])]">
    <Split>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ItemGroupOne',ID = '01')" mode="items" />
    </Split>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Details[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroup',ID)[1])]" mode="items">
    <ItemID name="{ID}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('ItemGroup',ID)"/>
    </ItemID>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Details"/>

  <xsl:template match="Details" mode="items"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The use of `mode` here is to avoid template conflicts.

Also note, for the final templates that ignore `Details`, you don't need the `not` logic in the condition here, as templates that match an element with a condition will have a higher priority than ones than just match the element with no condition.

Try it here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfr

Or, maybe write it like this, if you want to remove the use of the "mode" and the templates that ignore elements...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="ItemGroupOne" match="Details" use="ID = '01'"/>
  <xsl:key name="ItemGroup" match="Details" use="ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Items>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Details[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroupOne',ID = '01')[1])]" />
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Details">
    <Split>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('ItemGroupOne',ID = '01')[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ItemGroup',ID)[1])]">
        <ItemID name="{ID}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('ItemGroup',ID)"/>
        </ItemID>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Split>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```