# How to scrape text of a drop down menu using RSelenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape [this](https://derbis.dernekler.gov.tr/IstatistikDerneklerWeb/IlFaaliyetAlaniDernekler) site but I can't get any results. My code is:

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://derbis.dernekler.gov.tr/IstatistikDerneklerWeb/IlFaaliyetAlaniDernekler"

driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4445L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate(url)

option <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath',
                                    "//select[@id='cbIl']/option[@value='ADANA']")

option$clickElement()
```

[image]

My aim is to get the table by clicking the button after selecting the inputs I want. I'll write them in a loop and try all kinds of combinations and get the table, but I did not get the part I mentioned. Can you show me an example?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the option value is 1, not 'ADANA'
Rather it seems to be `@value="1"`

If you instead mean to look for the option that has text content 'ADANA', this is a question that has been asked and answered before, for example here:

[Xpath: how to select an option based on its text not value property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549256/xpath-how-to-select-an-option-based-on-its-text-not-value-property/1549271)

Comment: While technically correct, I'm inferring from the OP that the intent is to choose whichever `option` displays `"ADANA"`, regardless of its `value=`. (I'm inferring that the association of Adana to 1 is convenient enumeration: since this is selecting "cities", I don't think looking for `'1'` is the safest option.)

Comment: Well, yes. I was hoping it would jump the OP on a track to the correct answer.